# AWS rekognition: How to process the output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have got the output for aws-rekognition face detection. But I want to process the output i.e I want the cropped image to be stored in s3 bucket. So how to I process it and save it. Can anyone please help me with this? This is my output

```
{ JobStatus: 'SUCCEEDED',
 VideoMetadata:
 { Codec: 'h264',
  DurationMillis: 134802,
  Format: 'QuickTime / MOV',
  FrameRate: 23.976024627685547,
  FrameHeight: 534,
  FrameWidth: 1280 },
 Faces:
  [ { Timestamp: 4462, Face: { BoundingBox:
   { Width: 0.061342477798461914,
    Height: 0.1805628538131714,
    Left: 0.5905241966247559,
    Top: 0.23422487080097198 },
    Landmarks: [ { Type: 'eyeLeft',
     X: 0.6156551241874695,
     Y: 0.30313247442245483 },
    { Type: 'eyeRight',
     X: 0.6457341313362122,
     Y: 0.29226067662239075 },
    { Type: 'mouthLeft',
     X: 0.6207911968231201,
     Y: 0.38366419076919556 },
    { Type: 'mouthRight',
     X: 0.6457210779190063,
     Y: 0.3740907311439514 },
    { Type: 'nose', X: 0.6382492780685425, Y: 0.3447791337966919 } ],
     Pose:
     { Roll: -8.287483215332031,
      Yaw: 24.705015182495117,
      Pitch: -16.02778434753418 },
      Quality: { Brightness: 27.270671844482422, Sharpness: 5.775668621063232 },
      Confidence: 99.99810791015625 } }
 } ]
}
```

Comment: You will need to use a graphics library to extract the cropped rectangle, save to a file, then upload to Amazon S3. This is made harder by the fact that the data is stored in a video. What programming language are you using? What have you tried so far? This might also be of interest to you: [Automated video editing with YOU as the star! | AWS Machine Learning Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automated-video-editing-with-you-as-the-star/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo solution for this problem, implemented in Python 3 on Github. Please feel free to use it and adjust accordingly. I have a function that specifically does the cropping for you, provided the files are on your local machine.

See --> https://github.com/Kayokwa/multi_face_detection_and_search_using_aws_rekognition

Ciao!

Comment: The demo code that you provide search multiple faces in an image but the question its about extract the face of a video using the Timestamp and BoundingBox data provided by aws-rekognition